# Where can I find the list of all tendons in the human body?

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, anatomy, tendons

https://www.healthcentral.com/article/aging-can-take-major-toll-on-womens-tendons ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190527193757/https://www.healthcentral.com/article/aging-can-take-major-toll-on-womens-tendons)) claims that:

> There are about 4,000 tendons throughout the body.

This claim is echoed by [a fair amount of websites](https://www.google.com/search?q=4%2C000+tendons) but I couldn't find any 
decently trustworthy source.

Where can I find the list of all tendons in the human body?

I have only been able to find a [list of skeletal muscles of the human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_skeletal_muscles_of_the_human_body) so far. I'm surprised that there are 4000 tendons even though they are only ~640 muscles: most muscles that I am aware of are attached to fewer than six tendons (FYI: [Why some muscles have more tendons than others?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20576/630)).

Comment: Maybe that article is exaggerating?

Comment: @kmm maybe. Having a list would clarify it.

Comment: 640 muscles should be enough for anybody.

Comment: @dotancohen mark my words: after a few decades, every muscular system will have at least 2~8 Gigamuscles, and many will have 16+. Technological advance will not be stopped

Answer (score 23):

Your best bet is the [Terminologia Anatomica](http://www.unifr.ch/ifaa/Public/EntryPage/TA98%20Tree/Alpha/All%20KWIC%20EN.htm), which is the international standard for anatomical terminology.

The 1998 edition is [freely available](http://www.unifr.ch/ifaa/Public/EntryPage/TA98%20Tree/Alpha/All%20KWIC%20EN.htm). It lists only a few named tendons though, which is consistent with my experience as an anatomist: very few tendons are named separately from the muscles to which they are connected. Central tendon of the diaphragm, conjoint tendon, and calcaneal tendon are a few.

Otherwise, it's just "tendon of biceps brachii" (which actually has 2 tendons at one end and one at the other).

4,000 seems like a too high number to me. 2x the 640ish muscles plus some extra for multi-headed muscles and those with internal tendons or aponeurotic tendons seems like a more reasonable estimate.

Answer (score 12):

The [FMA](http://obofoundry.org/ontology/fma) lists 705 tendons, but note that it includes separate terms for left and right instances. As @kmm says, many of these simply shadow the list of skeletal muscles (and is likely incomplete).

You can [browse the list on OLS](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/ontologies/fma/terms?iri=http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.obolibrary.org%2Fobo%2FFMA_9721), or if you want to extract a table you can [query this SPARQL endpoint](http://sparql.hegroup.org/sparql), just type in the query here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?x ?v0 WHERE {
   ?x <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>+ 
       <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/FMA_9721> . 
   OPTIONAL {?x <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?v0}}
```